# Create child nodes using recursion

Tags: java, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a hierarchy from flat data.  I have the following `Node` definition:

```
public class Node {
        public String name;
        public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Given this data: `[Person,Manager,Hourly,New]`, where the tree should be like:

```
Person
  |--Manager
       |--Hourly
            |--New
```

I've tried the following:

```
public void run()
    {
        List<List<String>> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] str = {"Person","Manager","Hourly","New"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str)) ;

        String[] str2 = {"Person","Manager","Salary"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str2)) ;

        String[] str3 = {"Person","Manager","Salary", "New"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str3)) ;

        // Create a Node with the sequence
        myNode = new Node();
        createNode(objects.get(0), 0, myNode, myNode);
        LOG.debug(myNode.name);
}
```

And my `createNode` method is:

```
public Node createNode(List<String> seq, Integer start, Node parentNode, Node childNode)
    {
      // do something and return a Node?
    }
```

But conceptually I don't understand how to maintain the structure if Java is return-by-value.  What do I add to `createNode` so that I can add a Manager->Hourly->New hierarchy as a child to `Person`

Comment: What do you mean by saying Java is return-by-value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need both a `Node` return type *and* a `Node` argument to your method.

Here's one way to do it:

```
//in run()
myNode = new Node();
myNode.name = "Root";
createNode(objects.get(0), 0, myNode, myNode);



public void createNode(List<String> seq, Integer start, Node parentNode)
{
    Node childNode = new Node();
    childNode.name = seq[start];
    parentNode.children.Add(childNode);
    createNode(seq, start+1, childNode);
}
```

You don't need to return anything from `createNode()` -- since you have `parentNode` as a variable, you can add things to its `children` member.  A call to `createNode()` will recursively add child nodes, following your string array to its end.

Another way to do it is like this:

```
public Node createNode(List<String> seq, Integer start)
{
    if (start >= seq.Length) {
        return null;
    }
    Node node = new Node();
    node.name = seq[start];
    node.children.Add(createNode(seq, start+1);

    return node;
}
```

In this case, you don't need to pass in `node` references at all; calling `createNode()` will generate a new node object, fill its `children` tree recursively, and return the newly-generated node structure.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your defination of node is somewhat similar to adjacency list in graph. 
In the Target node add the associated node in the list associated with the target node. This is true for each node belonging to all the nodes.

For each object belonging to the objects array (array parameter) in your createNode method, you need to create the Node object. 
just pass an String array and the taeget node. Iterate the list and create a node. Add the node in the list.

To avoid duplicates while creating Node add them in an map. Key to the map should be String and value should be Node object. Before creating the object of node just try to get the object from the map, make the object only iff the object is not found in the map(in such a case create and add it to the map). In case object is found un the map, us the samedo not recreate it.